# Display fields node in table like views

Tags: views, nodes

I have a content type documents and my fields (created by admin) are:

- Doc1
- File
- Date
- Doc2
- File
- Date
- Doc3
  ...

The reason why I don't do a content type just with: "Doc, file, date" and add the nodes I want is because I need the Document name to be written by admin, and no one can edit it.(for example: birth certificate) (If you have an idea to do this other way, I'm listening)

This way, the user inserts just one node with all of those fields.

I want to somehow group those fields (Doc1, file, date) and display it like a view.

Views display all nodes from a content type. I need to display the fields of just one node, like a table. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view to display a single node. You can determine which node to display by using a contextual filter. For instance, you can pass the node ID to the view, in order to get it displayed.

There are many tutorials explaining how to use contextual filters with views. A possible starting point might be the following: https://www.drupal.org/node/1578558

Answer (score 1):

You could stick with the common practice: content-type with your fields and multiple nodes. There's a module called [field-permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions), where you can set a field permission e.g. to view and/or edit by admin only. I guess this will work.